# Can I toggle popup after a click event with a mouseout event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap to display popovers with a click event.  I'm requesting the info with the click event but I want to hide the popover after it looses focus so the user isn't required to click it again.  Is this possible?

Basically I want to show the popover with a click event but then when the launch point looses focus from the mouse the popover is hidden.

Here is a link to the popover doc from twitter-bootstrap: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers

This is what I'm currently doing:

jQuery:

```
$('.knownissue').on('click', function() {

    var el = $(this);

    if (el.data('showissue') == 'true') {
        el.popover('toggle');
        el.data('showissue', 'false');
        return;
    }

    $.post('functions/get_known_issues.php', function(data) {
       if (data.st) {
           el.attr('data-content', data.issue);
           el.popover('toggle');
           el.data('showissue', 'true');
       }
    }, "json");

});
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you try to explain more clearly what you are trying to do?

Comment: I added some more details.  Hopefully I made it clear.  Basically if a user clicks a <td> tag the popover is displayed but when they mouse out of the <td> tag the popover is hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work.

```
$('.knownissue').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).popover('hide');
});
```

Comment: Could work.  But whose to guarantee the mouse is even in the modal when it appears? And if it's a small modal, does that mean my wandering mouse hand isn't allowed to stray?

Comment: @Matt Did you read the question ? `"when the launch point looses focus from the mouse the popover is hidden"`. The `launch point` isn't the popup.

Comment: brilliant, not sure why I didn't see that.  Worked perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a custom jQuery event I call 'clickoutside'.  It gets fired if and only if you click the mouse *outside* of the target element.  It could easily be adapted for other event types (mousemove, keydown, etc).  In your case, when fired it could close your modal.

```
(function ($) {
    var count = 0;

    $.fn.clickoutside = function (handler) {
        // If the source element does not have an ID, give it one, so we can reference it
        var self = $(this);
        var id = self.attr('id');
        if (id === '') {
            id = 'clickoutside' + count++;
            self.attr('id', id);
        }

        // Watch for the event everywhere
        $('html').click(function (e) {
            var source = $(e.target);

            // ... but, stop it from propagating if it is inside the target 
            // element. The result being only events outside the target
            // propagate to the top.
            if (source.attr('id') == id || source.parents('#' + id).length > 0) {
                return;
            }

            handler.call(this, e);
        })
    };
})(jQuery);

 $('#targetElement').clickoutside(function(){ 
 });
```

EDIT: Example [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ZETYc/)